# Interpreting zero-inflated regression summary

Tags: r, statistics, regression

The output of the zeroinfl regression from pscl provides a list of coefficients under "count model coefficients" as well as a list of coefficients under "zero-inflation model coefficients."

Given the interest is to follow the z inflated model, what is the utility of the count model coefficients? Is it simply provided for reference?

Answer (score 3):

Your zero inflated regression consists of two models. The *zero* part is usually a binomial part, such as a logit or probit model, and accounts for the probability that Y is not zero. The *count* part is usually a model for count data (usually integers), such as a poisson or negative binomial model, and only considers those observations that are not zero. When you compare the number of observations of both models, e.g. using `summary(fit)`, you will see the difference. In sum, your *zero model* calculates the probability that an observations is not zero, the *count model* fits a model on those observations that are not zero.

This zero inflated regression is similar to a hurdle model. You can read more on this at [*Cross Validated: What is the difference between zero-inflated and hurdle models?*](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/81457/what-is-the-difference-between-zero-inflated-and-hurdle-models). BTW that platform is actually better suited for this kind of merely statistical questions.